# Tornar div visível após encontrar com outra div na rolagem da página

Tags: jquery

Como seria possível tornar uma div visível após esta encontrar com outra div na rolagem da página, utilizando javascript ou jQuery?

Comment: Munir, de uma olhada nesse plugin http://janpaepke.github.io/ScrollMagic/,

Comment: Muito Obrigado pela dica Erick!